# Health insurance after getting Hungarian birth certificate

Tags: immigration, eu-citizens, health-insurance, hungarian-citizens, ehic

I've just got my Hungarian birth certificate and my residency card. I'm now in Budapest but I'm about to leave permanently to France. I'd like to do a health insurance as a EU citizen but I don't know how. I heard that there's a card called EHIC, but I don't know how to do it or where to pay for it. I'm open also for other options.

How can I do a health insurance that will hold in France as well?

Answer (score 5):

The EU/EEA has a coordination system for social security (which includes national health insurance). One of the fundamental rules of this system is that you are always subject to exactly one national social/health insurance system. Which country you are insured in is determined by a set of rules or (in complicated cases) by a decision of the relevant national authority. You do not get to choose where to pay your health insurance.

As a few examples, you will be insured in the country where:

- You work (if you work as an employee or a self-employed person in only one country)
- You live (if you work in multiple states simultaneously)
- You worked last (if you're unemployed and e.g. receiving unemployment benefit after being employed somewhere)
- You live (if you're unemployed and not receiving any benefits or you have never worked anywhere in the EU/EEA)

http://ec.europa.eu/social/main.jsp?catId=851

The country where you are insured will also issue you an EHIC card. This card entitles you to urgent healthcare in any other EU/EEA state. It does not give you full health coverage (including non-urgent care) everywhere. However, in some cases, you can be fully covered in multiple countries at the same time, for example if you're a cross-border worker (returning home at least weekly).

http://ec.europa.eu/social/main.jsp?catId=559

Depending on your exact circumstances and your current status, you may first get a Hungarian EHIC card which you would then have to return when you move to France, where you will get a French EHIC. Or if you're going to move really soon, you may get to skip the Hungarian part completely.

Comment: i'm flying tomorrow for 4 years. On the site of the french EHIC https://www.service-public.fr/particuliers/vosdroits/F213 it's written I need a 13-digits social security number. Is it written on my residency card?

Comment: That's something called NIR, which you will get when you register for health/social insurance (or your employer registers you). See https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Num%C3%A9ro_de_s%C3%A9curit%C3%A9_sociale_en_France

Comment: @Heisenberg You don't need en EHIC to receive care in France if you are insured through the French insurance system (as is likely to be the case, as TooTea explained).

Comment: @TooTea It's useful to know that nobody calls it that in practice. "Numéro de sécurité sociale” or, typically, “numéro de sécu” is what people use.